# CSS hover selector for background-color not working after dynamic change of background-color with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I dynamically change the background color of a div with the jquery `.css()` method. I also want to have a CSS `hover` selector on that same div that changes the background color. It seems that before the color is changed with jquery, the CSS `hover` selector works, but after the div is changed with the jquery method, the CSS `hover` selector no longer works. Is there a way to work around this (without using the jquery `hover` method)?

This is an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/KVmCt/1/

Comment: what about having both of them add a class that changes the background color?

Comment: What's the selector you have for the div and what's the selector you used for the jQuery method? Can you show some of those lines?

Comment: @w0rldart updated with code example

Comment: @DavidThomas Huh? What I'm saying is that the `hover` selector should be working, even after I set the color on DOM ready with jquery. But it's not.

Comment: My apologies (and previous comment deleted), I thought you were meaning the jQuery `hover()` method, rather than the CSS `:hover`. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @DavidThomas no problem :) I could have been a bit clearer

Comment: You **need** to be clearer with your questions, especially seeing as you've been around for quite some time and have asked a couple hundred questions already.

Comment: Nice question. Nice Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is the importance of the location of the CSS information:

An external stylesheet is over-ruled by CSS in the head of the document; which is, in turn, over-ruled by CSS in the `style` attribute of the element. Basically the last style encountered by the browser overrides any previously specified, and otherwise-conflicting, rules (unless the keyword of `!important` is used).

As JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, places its CSS/styling information into the in-line `style` attribute of the element this *always* overrides conflicting styles specified elsewhere.

The places more importance on the `color: red` for the `div`, disregarding the `div:hover` styles.

To work around it, you can use:

```
div:hover {
    background-color: blue!important;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KVmCt/10/).

A better solution, though, is to avoid assigning the `background-color`/other styles with jQuery, and simply use CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: blue!important;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's `hover()` method:

```
$('div').css('background-color','red').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KVmCt/11/).

Comment: @Justin - I've never had an occasion to use jQuery's `.css()` method, instead toggling classes on the DOM elements as in stecb's comment to Nicole's answer - but for just hovering there's no need for javascript at all, as David says here.

Comment: My first response, when I experienced this problem was to just use jQuery's `.hover()` to set it back up the way I had written it in CSS, however, to my surprise and dismay, it was still inactive (even though the script for the `.hover()` function came after the other dynamically changing background-color scripts). If I had known that specifying the rule in the CSS as `!important` would have worked I never would have tried to correct this with code in the first place, but thankfully this answer gave me the perfect fix. I will be keeping this more in the forefront of my mind, in the future.

Comment: The "!important" solution worked for me when I had a JQuery command change a class' background-color, and that command was somehow disabling a CSS-defined hover effect. Oddly, the JQuery disabled the hover effect's background-color property but not its cursor property. Anyway it works now by adding !important to the CSS, so thanks.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time! This is happening with react also. Thanks man!

Answer (score 7):

The jquery `css` method adds an inline style to your elements, which means that after executing it, your div will look like

```
<div style="background-color: red">Hello world</div>`
```

Now, inline styling has always more priority than css styling, hence your problem.

So, why not adding a css class instead of using inline styling? Try with the following:

```
$("div").addClass("edited");
```

and

```
div:hover, div.edited:hover {
   background-color: blue;
}

div.edited {
   background-color: red;
}
```

and you'll see it works.

Comment: Since the problem has nothing to do with jQuery, use `document.querySelector("div").classList.add("edited");` in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 3):

When you manipulate css with jQuery it adds it inline and overrides any css in a stylesheet try using jquery to add and remove a class that changes the color on hover. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KVmCt/6/

jQuery looks like this:

```
$("div").hover(
function(){
$(this).addClass("blue");
 }
,
function(){
$(this).removeClass("blue");
});
```

Comment: or directly just 1 function containing `$(this).toggleClass("blue");` as parameter of the hover method. ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you just need to delete the inline style you can use

```
$("#yourselector").attr("style", " ");
```

It will replace your inline style with `style=" "`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add the important tag to your CSS.

```
div:hover {
    background-color: blue !important;
};
```