# jQuery CSS disables the original hover-style

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div called "msg_div" and in the styles.css I have a line like this:

```
.msg_div:hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

Now I added this script to a page:

```
$(".msg_div").css("background-color", "#FFF");
$(this).css("background-color", "#EEE");
```

But now there isn't any hover style anymore.
How can I fix this?

My intention is that when I click a box, the grey background should switch to the clicked div.

**Edit (this is the HTML code):**

```
<script>
    $(".msg_posteingang_div").click(function(){
        $(".msg_div").css("background-color", "#FFF");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#EEE");
    })
</script>
<div class="msg_div">Message 1</div>
<div class="msg_div">Message 2</div>
<div class="msg_div">Message 3</div>
<div class="msg_div">Message 4</div>
```

**Edit 2:**
The solution is to create a style (in styles.css) for the `.msg_div` class itself not just for the `:hover`.

My styles.css now:

```
.msg_div { padding:5px; cursor: pointer; }
.msg_div:hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

Comment: _"I have a div called "msg_div" and in the styles.css I have a line like this:.msg-div:hover { background-color: #eee; }"_ See dash `-` at `css` , `_` underscore at `js` ?

Comment: Im sorry this was a writing fail :/ Because when I delete the js, the hover works perfectly

Comment: What is `$(this)` referencing at `js` ? _"My intention is that when I click a box, the grey background should switch to the clicked div."_ `click` event not appear defined at Question ? , but `css` `:hover` ? Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: `$(this)` is only the one object the user clicked and not the whole class `.msg_box`. I can include html

Comment: Can include `.msg_posteingang_div` `html` ?

Answer (score 0):

you are using msg-div in your css. and msg_div in your javascript.
make sure your elements are named correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to the hover `background-color` style:

```
.msg_div:hover { background-color: #eee!important; }
```

Here is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e9d5e67c/1/

Note this solution is the quickest one (but works:)), and you may want to read why this is happening and try a better solution described here: [CSS hover selector for background-color not working after dynamic change of background-color with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949194/css-hover-selector-for-background-color-not-working-after-dynamic-change-of-back)